# Vue form validation issue

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I am trying to build my own simple form validation(modeled after **laravel** form validation) with **vue** that I plan to use on a project that am currently working.

My issue is peculiar in that when I click the submit button the form validation errors don't show up but when I right-click on any of the input elements and I select inspect element as shown below the errors then show up.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

I have tested this with both chrome and firefox and they both showing the same issue and there are no code errors in the any of the browser consoles.

Code files that am currently working with are

**Demo.vue**

```js
<template>
    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <form @submit.prevent="submit" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
        <div
            class="form-group has-feedback"
            :class="{
                'has-error': errors.has('username') || errors.has('message')
            }"
        >
            <input
                type="text"
                v-model.trim="form.username"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Username"
                required
            />
            <span
                class="help-block"
                v-if="errors.has('username') || errors.has('message')"
            >{{ errors.get('username') || errors.get('message') }}</span>
        </div>
        <div
            class="form-group has-feedback"
            :class="{ 'has-error': errors.has('password') }"
        >
            <input
                type="password"
                v-model.trim="form.password"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                autocomplete="off"
                required
            />
            <span
                class="help-block"
                v-if="errors.has('password')"
            >{{ errors.get('password') }}</span>
        </div>
        <button
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"
        >Login</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import formMixin from '@/mixins/form';

export default {
    name: 'demo',
    mixins: [formMixin],
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                username: '',
                password: '',
            },
            rules: {
                username: 'required',
                password: 'required',
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.validate();

            if (this.errors.any()) {
                return;
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**mixins/form.js**

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import Errors from '@/utils/Errors';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            errors: new Errors(),
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getLabel(field) {
            let fieldLabel = null;

            if (this.labels && this.labels[field]) {
                fieldLabel = this.labels[field];
            }

            return fieldLabel;
        },

        handleRequired(field, value) {
            let label = this.getLabel(field);
            const message = `${label ? label : 'Field'} is required`;

            if (!value) {
                this.errors.set(field, message);
            }
        },

        process() {
            Object.keys(this.rules).forEach((key) => {
                this.rules[key].split('|').forEach((rule) => {
                    this[`handle${_.startCase(rule)}`](key, this.form[key]);
                });
            });
        },

        validate() {
            this.process();
        },
    },
};
```

**utils/Errors.js**

```js
export default class Errors {
    constructor() {
        this.errors = {};
    }

    any() {
        return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
    }

    has(field) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.errors, field);
    }

    set(field, error) {
        this.errors[field] = error;
    }


    get(field) {
        if (this.errors[field]) {
            return typeof this.errors[field] === 'string'
                ? this.errors[field]
                : this.errors[field][0];
        }

        return '';
    }

    record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    clear(field) {
        if (field) {
            delete this.errors[field];
            return;
        }

        this.errors = {};
    }
}
```

What could be causing this to happen?

Thank you.